# When should I use a WaitHandle instead of a lock

Tags: c#, locking, waithandle

In `C#`, when we should use `WaitHandle` instead of `lock` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lock is fundamentally different from a `WaitHandle`. With a lock you write, for example:

```
lock (SomeResource)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

The first line says, "I want exclusive access to that resource," and will wait until that resource is available (i.e. nobody else has a lock on it). Then the code runs and at the end the lock is released so that others can use it.

`WaitHandle` is used to wait for some event to take place. When you write:

```
MyWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Your code is waiting for some other thread (possibly in a different process) to signal that `WaitHandle`. What it signals could be anything. Perhaps you're waiting for another thread to finish its job and say, "I'm done now," before your code can continue.

So, to answer your question, you should use a lock when you want to gain exclusive access to a resource. You should use `WaitHandle` when you want to be notified of some event.

Comment: +1 for last two lines which is a clear criteria for choosing between when both can be applied (usually it's clear which one to use).

Answer (score 3):

When you need it. Seriously, lock is syntactic sugar with `Monitor`, which probably uses WaitHandles internally.

Only use it if you need more flexibility (like e.g. holding on to a lock longer than the current scope...) or manage multiple locks in the right order etc.

Answer (score 3):

They accomplish completely different things. A `lock` is used to limit access to a specific block of code to a *single* thread at a time. A `WaitHandle` is the base class for several concurrency-related classes, such as `Semaphore`, `Mutex`, `AutoResetEvent`, and `ManualResetEvent`, which allow you to control concurrency in slightly different ways. For instance, a `Semaphore` allows you to limit concurrency to *no more than **N*** threads, instead of a single thread.

Comment: "Completely different" things don't generally involve one thing being a subset of the other. They are conceptually related and usage can overlap. They both relate to accessing blocks of code. Semaphores limit access to no more than N threads. If N is 1, then functionality is much like a lock. Clearly WaitHandle covers a broad range of things, but dealing in the area of concurrency. If you were teaching WaitHandles to someone who only knew locks, you wouldn't disallow the bridge of thought, you'd start with it.

Answer (score 2):

A WaitHandle can wait for multiple handles, a lock can wait for only one.

Answer (score 1):

`WaitHandle` is often used when you have multiple threads running and you want to wait for one or all of them to complete before you continue to do some other action.  `lock` would be used if you want to prevent multiple threads from accessing a shared resource at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation lies in these two links. Unfortunately you're going to have to do some reading to get a full answer to the type of question you asked:

This contains an example as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kad9xah9.aspx